# How to get youtube mix playlist?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using Python 3, I was able to get a playlist and get an individual video, but I want to get the mix playlist of each user (public mix), since every user see different mixes.

Should I authenticate users using google auth and then grab the mix like I grab a normal playlist? If so, how to send the auth token with Youtube's API request? I couldn't find anything related to the mix in the docs.

Do mixes have a unique URL that I could use to grab them without authentication?

I'm currently using [Pafy](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy), it's a wrapper for Youtube's API, but neither that library nor the official API has a way to get the info off Youtube's mix, my code is below

```
def get_youtube_playlist(url):
    playlist = pafy.get_playlist(url)
    for item in playlist['items']:
        return item['pafy'].title
```

That works with playlists, not mixes.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita I just edited my question, but my code is irrelevant to my question, because I haven't found a way to get mixes.

Comment: @Lynob I posted an answer. It may not help you in your specific case *(using python)*, but I hope it may give you another new idea(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that YouTube API has the required functionality for retrieve the mix playlist *(and I couldn't find any info about it, actually)*.

Saying this, I want share the discovery I made:

---

Let's say you want a mix from the video "[Eminem - Lose Yourself (Explicit)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPA2czkOsFE)".

This is the URL of the video:

> Eminem - Lose Yourself (Explicit)
>
> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPA2czkOsFE`

If you want get the mix playlist of this video, you can modify the URL as follows:

> Mix: Eminem - Lose Yourself (Explicit)
>
> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPA2czkOsFE&start_radio=1&list=RDnPA2czkOsFE`

These additional parameters are found in mix playlists generated by YouTube.

Explanation:

- `start_radio=1`: No idea, IMHO, but if anyone can find any information about it, please, consider edit this question and add it.
- `list=RD`: IMHO, this settings indicates that the declared `videoId` will be used for generate the mix playlist - by adding the "RD" letters + `videoId`.

So, if you enter the modified URL, you'll get: [Mix: Eminem - Lose Yourself (Explicit)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPA2czkOsFE&start_radio=1&list=RDnPA2czkOsFE).

---

Making more testings, I discovered also that the `start_radio=1` is not needed for "create" an mix playlist using a given video.

Using other example, let's say: [Ludwig Van Beethoven's 5th Symphony in C Minor (Full)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOk8Tm815lE):

This is the URL:

> Ludwig Van Beethoven's 5th Symphony in C Minor (Full)
>
> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOk8Tm815lE`

After the modifications made in the URL, the result is:

> Mix: Ludwig Van Beethoven's 5th Symphony in C Minor (Full)
>
> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOk8Tm815lE&list=RDfOk8Tm815lE`

N.B that in this case, the `start_radio=1` is not required and the result will be: [Mix: Ludwig Van Beethoven's 5th Symphony in C Minor (Full)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOk8Tm815lE&list=RDfOk8Tm815lE)

---

Side note: I really hope this discovery won't be removed.

Comment: Nice discovery! I will accept it in a month from now if no one else has a solution to the problem, because if I accept the answer right now, the question will disappear from the feed.