# How to retrieve first playlist video on youtube using youtube-dl python?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am new here and new for Python.
recently i've code how to convert video from youtube.

so far my code is running smoothly. however, since i copy url link that containt playlist video like this :

[playlist video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmJwz.jpg)

and it turn up error like this :

[Error Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0zZw.jpg)

[Error Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro0VA.jpg)

Here is my file called App.py (only to retrieve information video) :

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, url_for, redirect, send_file
from extractor import extract_video_data_from_url

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
      return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/download", methods=["POST"])
def download():
   video_url = request.form["video_url"]
   video_data = extract_video_data_from_url(video_url)
   return render_template("Download.html",video_data=video_data)
```

and this is my another file called extractor.py :

```
import os
import json

def extract_format_data(format_data):
    extension = format_data["ext"]
    format_name = format_data["format"]
    url = format_data["url"]
    return {
        "extension": extension,
        "format_name": format_name,
        "url": url
    }
        
def extract_video_data_from_url(url):
    command = f'youtube-dl "{url}" -j'
    output = os.popen(command).read()
    video_data = json.loads(output)
    title = video_data["title"]
    formats = video_data["formats"]
    thumbnail = video_data["thumbnail"]
    formats = [extract_format_data(format_data) for format_data in formats]
    return {
        "title": title,
        "formats": formats,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail
    }
```

and for `/download` itself i only put `{{video_data}}` in my html.

i found answer for another thread that have to add  `--playlist-start 1` on `youtube-dl` syntax in extractor.py but have still same.

do you guys can assist me?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE : actually, when i started to download Short Youtube Video, it also can't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first image is a "mix" auto-generated playlist by YouTube for this video:

> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKt_Qf1T22o&list=RDqKt_Qf1T22o`

You can [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262410/12511801) how to get the "Mix" of a given video.

Since this is an *auto-generated* playlist, you need more code to add for see how you can get the videos on that auto-generated playlist and then loop those videos.

As far as I understand your code (*I might be wrong, though*), your `extract_video_data_from_url` function receives a YouTube video URL, so, if you manage to loop the videos inside that playlist, you can call `extract_video_data_from_url` on each iteration of items (*i.e videos*) inside then given playlist.

Comment: The problem is, i wanna took only 1 video (first video) inside that playlist, not all videos.
but recently i have some clue that whatever url link that contains ampersand symbol. it cannot works. let say that playlist consist url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKt_Qf1T22o&list=RDqKt_Qf1T22o&start_radio=1

after &list=RDqKt_Qf1T22o&start_radio=1 cannot be read and error.